# how to show all groups in user dashboard?

Tags: groups, user-dashboard

In our system, we have some groups that only a manager can add or remove people to, however we would still like the contacts to be able to see that they are included in those groups via their contact dashboard.  Any group membership that is listed as "user and user admin only" management settings are not showing up in the contact dashboard. While the "public pages" settings seem to be needed to have the group show up in the dashboard, we don't want the users to be able to unsubscribe from some key organizational roles.
Is there either a way for all subscribed groups to be shown in the user's contact dashboard? (preferred) or a way to limit showing the unsubscribe link on these (many) critical org roles?  Thanks much!
*using civi 5.2.2 and drupal 7

Comment: With Drupal 7 you can use the Views in CiviCRM Dashlets module to add Views to the dashboard...https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_views_dashlets

Comment: Cool, sounds like a good solution - will check it out!